# Linking User to Profile with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am moving a legacy winform app to the web and would like some advice on forms authentication. Am I correct in assuming that forms authentication is better than rolling up my own user authentication functionality?

It would be easy enough to roll my own since the this is what the winform application did and the table structure already supports it, but forms authentication looks like it would do a much better job securing the site and the user authentication info.

I'm an old programmer, but pretty young in web dev and I have learned over the years that using MS built in tools sometimes looks better than it works...forms authentication isn't one of those cases is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that Forms Authentication is a case where you're likely to experience no "buyers remorse".  You can opt in to use some pretty nice features.  The model is very flexible because it allows you to [implement your own Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Using forms authentication doesn't means you don't get to use those tables. You will do the check for username/password, and tell asp.net that the user is authenticated. Asp.net will continue from there, ensuring further requests from that user are identified and authenticated (based on an authentication ticket).

**Update 1:** Later on asp.net included membership providers, with some controls for it. Even then you can still implement your own membership provider, which in really simple cases you can do by implementing only 1 or 2 of the methods. If you have several features, and they don't map well with what the membership provider supports, I would stick to a custom implementation.